# trying a code to download PDF files from but PDF doc is not viewed

Tags: android, pdf

I'm trying a code to download PDF files from dropbox and after downloading all file in my SD card when clicked on item then PDF book should be loaded in PDF viewer system app.
But actually by using this code all PDF files are downloading but when PDF app is loaded it shows the error "the document could not be opened" and PDF book is not viewed. Can anyone please help me to sort this problem
Thanking you in advance
And i'm not good to post question in efficient manners so i'm really sorry in advance.

```
  {

  MainActivity
  package com.example.mahvishponum.pdfviewer;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.content.DialogInterface;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Environment;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncResponse {

  ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
  ListView list;
  int counter = 0;

  ArrayList<DataModel> _data = new ArrayList<>();
  String[] web = {
        "A Textbook of Paediatric Orthopaedics" +
                "By Nigel S. Broughton",
        "Basic Pediatric Protocols 2013" +
                "By Ministry of Health Kenya",
        "Basic Pediatric Protocols 2016" +
                "By Ministry of Health Kenya",

        "Current Diagnosis & Treatment" +
                "PEDIATRICS 19th Edition" +
                "By McGrawHill LANGE",
        "Hospital Care For Children" +
                "Pocket Book 2013 Edition" +
                "By WHO",
        "Textbook of Pediatrics" +
                "20th Edition" +
                "By Nelson",
        "The Care and Feeding of Children" +
                "By L. Emmett Holt. M. D.",
        "Updates on the Management of Severe Acute Malnutrition in Infants 
          and Children" +
                "Guidelines by WHO"
};
String[] titles = {
        "helptextbookpedortho.pdf",
        "BasicPaediatricProcotolsNovember2013.pdf",
        "basicpaediatricprotocols2016.pdf",
        "currentdiagnosisandtreatmentpediatrics.pdf",
        "HospitalCareForChildrenPocketBooks.pdf",
        "NelsonTextbookofPediatrics.pdf",
        "TheCareAndFeedingOfChildren.pdf"
};
String[] urls = {
        "https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruds35lyz672jjk/helptextbookpedortho.pdf?dl=1",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2snurxnvijbqya/BasicPaediatricProcotolsNovember2013.pdf?dl=1",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1tyrfqd5jhdu7k/basicpaediatricprotocols2016.pdf?dl=1",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/s/hgs7pp97ut3mti3/currentdiagnosisandtreatmentpediatrics.pdf?dl=1",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvz2805gj39hbc4/HospitalCareForChildrenPocketBooks.pdf?dl=1",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/s/avlj81qctl83otk/NelsonTextbookofPediatrics.pdf?dl=1",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0e5p9hx6jwf2kg/TheCareAndFeedingOfChildren.pdf?dl=1",
        "https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtfurbb0umbns03/WHOMalnutritionGuidelines.pdf?dl=1"
};
Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.book,
        R.drawable.book,
        R.drawable.book,
        R.drawable.book,
        R.drawable.book,
        R.drawable.book,
        R.drawable.book,
        R.drawable.book

};

void filSdCard() {
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    if (counter < urls.length) {

        final Downloader downloadTask = new Downloader(MainActivity.this, mProgressDialog, titles[counter], urls[counter],counter);
        downloadTask.delegate = MainActivity.this;
        downloadTask.execute();
        mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                downloadTask.cancel(true);
            }
        });

    }


}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pdfviewer);

    CustomList adapter = new
            CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listvid);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

        //give the title according to the title of your disease. every file 
        should have different title.
            if (ifFileExists(titles[position])) {
                String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pediatric/" + "helptextbookpedortho.pdf";

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(filePath));
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filePath), "application/pdf");
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                //constructor contains url as well as title with which the file will be saved. make sure you give the same title here and above.
                //Also look at the url im using. you can see these files on your dropbox and see we have a different url. upload file to dropbox and make it public to get url, then compare it with any
                //of these urls, you will know what to replace.
                filSdCard();

            }
        }
    });
}

boolean ifFileExists(String title) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Pediatric");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(myDir, title);
    if (file.exists()) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}

@Override
public void processFinish(String output) {
    if (output.equals("Success")) {
        if (counter < urls.length) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            filSdCard();
        }

    } else {
        if(mProgressDialog.isShowing())
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private class DataModel {
    String Title = "";
    String Url = "";

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return Url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        Url = url;
    }
}
}
}











 Downloader.java
 package com.example.mahvishponum.pdfviewer;

 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.os.PowerManager;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;

 /**
 * Created by Mahvish on 6/6/2017.
 */

public class Downloader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private Context context;
String title="";
public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
int counter=0;
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
String urlString ="";
public Downloader(Context context, ProgressDialog mProgressDialog, String 
title, String urlString, int counter) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mProgressDialog = mProgressDialog;
    this.title = title;
    this.urlString = urlString;
    this.counter = counter;

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
        // instead of the file
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                    + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
        }

        // this will be useful to display download percentage
        // might be -1: server did not report the length
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        input = connection.getInputStream();
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/Pediatric");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(myDir, title);

        output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte data[] = new byte[4096];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            // allow canceling with back button
            if (isCancelled()) {
                input.close();
                return null;
            }
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e.toString();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null)
                output.close();
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }

        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user
    // presses the power button during download
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            getClass().getName());
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading "+(counter+1)+"/"+8 );
    mProgressDialog.show();
 }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setSecondaryProgress(30);

    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    mWakeLock.release();
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
     if (result != null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Download error: " + result, 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        delegate.processFinish("Error");

    } else {
         delegate.processFinish("Success");

       /* String mediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
  "/Pediatric/" + title;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
  Uri.parse(mediaPath));
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(mediaPath), "video/mp4");
        context. startActivity(intent);*/
    }
  }
}







 AsyncResponse Inteerface
 package com.example.mahvishponum.pdfviewer;

 /**
 * Created by Mahvish on 12/22/2016.
  */

 public interface AsyncResponse {
 void processFinish(String output);

 }







 pdfviewer.xml

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <ListView
   android:id="@+id/listvid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 </ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>







Menifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mahvishponum.pdfviewer">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


  </application>

  </manifest>

CustomList.java
 package com.example.mahvishponum.pdfviewer;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

 private final Activity context;
 private final String[] web;
 private final Integer[] imageId;
 public CustomList(Activity context,
              String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
  super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
  this.context = context;
 this.web = web;
this.imageId = imageId;

 }
 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
   View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

  imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
  return rowView;
 }
 }


list_single.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <TableRow>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

 </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you open it from the normal data file manager / Own Files? If this don't work, the download goes wrong

Here change the code to this in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listvid);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                //give the title according to the title of your disease. every file
                //should have different title.
                if (ifFileExists(titles[position])) {
                    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pediatric/" + "helptextbookpedortho.pdf";
                    File f = new File(filePath);
                    Log.d("Main","file exits " + f.exists());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(filePath));
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "application/pdf");
                    //intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filePath), "application/pdf");
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    //constructor contains url as well as title with which the file will be saved. make sure you give the same title here and above.
                    //Also look at the url im using. you can see these files on your dropbox and see we have a different url. upload file to dropbox and make it public to get url, then compare it with any
                    //of these urls, you will know what to replace.
                    filSdCard();

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have changed this lines:

```
File f = new File(filePath);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "application/pdf");
```

Comment: But i want to view it when clicked on the list item

Comment: Yes I know, but now we know it goes wrong in your code ;)

Comment: I can try. Can you post the code from the CustomList class

Comment: i updated other activities too, thanks for your favor :)

Comment: the answer is posted :)

Comment: how to mark it correct?? i mean what is the process??

Comment: Thank You for providing the link :)